# Markdown support in hugo blog post's title?

Tags: go, markdown, hugo

Hugo has its front matter where it supports TOML format.

> +++
>    date = "2016-11-15T09:36:44+05:30"
>    draft = true
>    title = "Grab it for <s>$100</s> $40"
>    +++

Here I used `<s>$100</s>` to strike through $100,  but I am unable to do the same in hugo post, inside that front matter. So Hugo doesn't support markdown in title?, Is there any workaround for it?

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
{{ .Title | markdownify }}
```

in your layout that is generating the title. It is usually found at `layouts/`.